# As a Nepali Passport holder, do I need a visa to travel to Jeju Island?

Tags: nepali-citizens, kathmandu, jeju

I am planning to visit Jeju island for a week in April 2019. Do I need a visa to travel there?

Answer (score 3):

You **do** require a visa.

> **1. Nationals of the following countries are NOT included in the visa-free entry
>   into Jeju Special Self-Governing Province (24 countries)**
>
> Iran, Sudan, Syria, Macedonia, Cuba, Kosovo, Palestine, Afghanistan, Iraq, Ghana,
>   Nigeria, Yemen, Egypt, Gambia, Senegal, Bangladesh, Kyrgyz, Pakistan, Somalia,
>   Uzbekistan, Nepal, Cameroon, Sri Lanka, Myanmar

Source: [Ministry of Foreign Affairs, Republic of Korea](http://overseas.mofa.go.kr/my-en/brd/m_1914/view.do?seq=761537&srchFr=&srchTo=&srchWord=&srchTp=&multi_itm_seq=0&itm_seq_1=0&itm_seq_2=0&company_cd=&company_nm=&page=1)

This list was different before and the new list is in effect **since August 1, 2018**